# Python - update item in an existing json file

Tags: python, json, file

I want to update `float` `values` inside my `json` file, structured like this:

```
{"Starbucks": {"Roads": 1.0, "Pyramid Song": 1.0, "Go It Alone": 1.0}}
```

So whenever I generate an already existing playlist, with the exact same items, I increment `key` `values` by +`1.0`.

I have a file opened with `'append'` option

```
with open('pre_database/playlist.json', 'a') as f:
     if os.path.exists('pre_database/playlist.json'):
         #update json here
     json.dump(playlist,f)
```

but this `'a'` method would append another `dictionary` to `json`, and it would generate `parsing` problems later on.

likewise, if I use `'w'` method, it would overwrite the file entirely.

what is the best solution for updating the values?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could open the file in `r+` mode (opens the file for both reading and writing), read in the JSON content, *seek* back to the start of the file, truncate it and then rewrite the modified dictionary back to the file:

```
if os.path.exists('pre_database/playlist.json'):
    with open('pre_database/playlist.json', 'r+') as f:
         playlist = json.load(f)
         # update json here
         f.seek(0)
         f.truncate()
         json.dump(playlist, f)
```

Comment: @data_garden It does, but you need to read from the file first before it gets truncated, so `w` won't work here. You need to manually truncate.

Answer (score 2):

`Appending` means that your file is getting longer, which is neither what you what nor how JSON works.

If you want to update some value you need to load the json-file, update your value(s) and dump it back:

```py
with open('pre_database/playlist.json', 'r') as f:
    playlist = json.load(f)
playlist[key] = value  # or whatever
with open('pre_database/playlist.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(playlist, f)
```

Also your check if your file exists should happen *before* you open the file and not when it's already open:

```py
if os.path.exists('pre_database/playlist.json'):
    with open('pre_database/playlist.json', 'r') as f:
        playlist = json.load(f)
    playlist[key] = value  # or whatever
    with open('pre_database/playlist.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(playlist, f)
```

although I guess the pythonic ways would be to just try it and catch the `IOError` if the file didn't exist as expected.

Depending on how you continue it's probably best to do something like this:

```py
try:
    with open('pre_database/playlist.json', 'r') as f:
        playlist = json.load(f)
except IOError, ValueError:
    playlist = default_playlist

playlist[key] = value  # or whatever

with open('pre_database/playlist.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(playlist, f)
```

Robin

Answer (score 0):

It is appendind new dictionary because file is opened in append mode and cursor is at end of file. You need to truncate before dumping latest dict to file

```
with open('pre_database/playlist.json', 'a') as f:
    if os.path.exists('pre_database/playlist.json'):
        f.seek(0)
        playlist = json.load(f)
        #Update your dict here
        playlist.update(dict({'key1':'NewValue1'}))
        f.truncate(0)
        playlist.dump(playlist,f)
```